# Matlab subscript indices error

Tags: matlab, subscript

help me please. i always get a subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logical error whenever i put 0 value on my "data" how can i get rid of it, i need to have a zero on that one. whenever there is a zero Voltage(1,0) = 1. but I can't get through.

```
Voltage = [0 1 1 3 4 1; 1 0 5 4 5 3; 6 4 0 4 5 7; 9 3 4 0 6 4; 7 8 5 6 0 7; 4 5 6 7 3 0];
data =[0 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 2 3 4 5; 4 5 6 7; 3 4 5 6; 1 3 5 7; 1 2 3 4; 3 4 5 6];
Vm = data(:,1);
Vn = data(:,2);
R = data(:,3);``
X1 = data(:,4);
sz=max(Vn)
y=1:sz
for Vm=data(:,1)
    if Vm==0
       Voltage(y,Vm)=1
       Voltage(y,Vm)=logical(Voltage(y,Vm));
       Current = Voltage(y,Vm)-Voltage(y,Vn);
    else Vm >= 1
       Current = Voltage(y,Vm)-Voltage(y,Vn);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference a value in the else statement in the `Voltage` matrix using `y` but `y` is not an integer it is an array (or 1d matrix). If you display `y` you will see that it is `1 2 3 4 5 6`. There are several sections of offending code, one of which is:

```
else Vm >= 1
    disp(y) # `y` is not an integer and therefore not a valid index.
    Current = Voltage(y,Vm)-Voltage(y,Vn);
```

To fix it, decide if `y` should be static or change in the loop.

Let me know if you want a further explanation.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help, i want further explanation, because i want my "y" to change on the loop. can you explain what can i do with it?

Comment: @well how do you want `y` to change? For example, do want to use the next value in the `y` matrix each time the else condition is met?

Comment: Yes, want it like that.

Comment: @well The `y` matrix has a length of 6 but your for loop runs through the first value for each row in `data` which is 8 values. If you give more detail on exactly what you are trying to do, helping will be easier.

Comment: what I'am trying to do is like this

Comment: (Voltage(1,0)-Voltage(1,2)); (Voltage(2,0)-Voltage(2,2)); (Voltage(3,0)-Voltage(3,2))...... (Voltage(6,0)-Voltage(6,2)) then it will transfer to the next row of tha "data" value of Vm(1st column of data) and Vn(2nd column of data) (Voltage(1,2)-Voltage(1,3)); (Voltage(2,2)-Voltage(2,3)).... (Voltage(6,2)-Voltage(6,3)).

Comment: if you replace the "0" in the data with any no. from 1-6, there will be an answer. and that what i want to get. but i really need to have that zero there. and the condition that i want to make is that if Vm is equal to 0(zero) Voltage(y,Vm) should be equal to 1(one) that make the original formula for the current=Voltage(y,Vm)-Voltage(y,Vn) to Current=1-Voltage(y,Vn).